# Combine similar functions into one (Python)

Tags: python

I have the following two very similar functions:

```
# Get value as int
def get_int(message):
    while True:
        try:
            number = int(input(message))
            return number
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input. Try again.")

# Get value as fraction
def get_fraction(message):
    while True:
        try:
            number = Fraction(input(message))
            return number
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input. Try again.")
```

Now I am wondering if that can be done in a simpler way, by combining these two functions into one.
This is my first attemt:

```
# Get value as specific data type
def get_value(message, data_type):
    while True:
        try:
            number = None
            match data_type:
                case "int":
                    number = int(input(message))
                case "fraction":
                    number = Fraction(input(message))
            return number
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input. Try again.")
```

So now I'm passing the data type as an argument. But I am sure there is a simpler way without using a case distinction. Can I pass somehow the real data datype to the function and use this directly in the code?

Comment: What is `Fraction`?

Comment: @Tomerikoo It's probably from here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html

Comment: FYI, you're on the verge of rediscovering the Strategy Pattern.

Answer (score 3):

Great news: types are first-order citizens in Python. You can do something like this:

```
def get_value(message, data_type):
    while True:
        try:
            return data_type(input(message))
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input. Try again.")
```

And then call it  like this:

```
get_value("Input an integer:", int)
# or,
get_value("Input a fraction:", Fraction)
```

Comment: Wow ok! Didn't think it could be that easy. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Python has [decorators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/) for this same task.

```
# the decorator
def calculate(function):
   
   # the wrapper function
   def wrapper(message):
        while True:
        try:
            number = function(message)
            return number
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input. Try again.")

   return wrapper
```

Now you just use this in your functions:

```
# Get value as int
@calculate
def get_int(message):
   return int(input(message))


# Get value as fraction
@calculate
def get_fraction(message):
    return Fraction(input(message))
```

What's happening here is you are defining a function, that takes a function as input. In this case, it is the `calculate` function. It is taking in the `get_int` and `get_fraction` function as inputs.

So when you call the function `get_init`, it is actually calling `calculate(get_init)` which is also a function that takes `message` as input.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I pass somehow the real data datype to the function and use this directly in the code?

There's nothing stopping you from passing the actual data type rather than a string:

```
# Get value as specific data type
def get_value(message, data_type):
    while True:
        try:
            number = data_type(input(message))
            return number
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input. Try again.")
```

Test:

```
print(get_value('Enter a fraction: ', Fraction))
```

Output:

```
Enter a fraction: 1/3
1/3
```

Comment: Thanks! Coming from other languages like Java it is amazing how intuitive python is.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass references to functions just like any other variable. Therefore:

```
def get_value(message, data_type):
  while True:
    try:
      return data_type(input(message))
    except ValueError:
      print('Invalid input. Try again')

x = get_value('Enter a fraction', Fraction)
y = get_value('Enter an integer', int)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the conversion function itself, rather than a string.

```
# Get value as specific data type
def get_value(message, converter):
    while True:
        try:
            number = converter(input(message))
            return number
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input. Try again.")

def get_int(message):
    return get_value(message, int)

def get_fraction(message):
    return get_value(message, Fraction)
```